# Как считать слово из файла в Паскале?

Tags: pascal

Не могу сообразить, нужна Ваша подсказка.
Можно использовать только packed array. Переменные типа string использовать нельзя. Т.е. использовать стандарт Паскаля, а не тубро и т.п.

Как мне считать слово и присвоить его переменной? Длина слова неизвестна.
Не могу сообразить механизм присваивания.

Comment: @Magos, массивы то да. Но текст в case и packed array нет. В этом я торможусь.

Answer (score 2):

считывайте посимвольно до первого пробела или знака препинания

Comment: @Magos, это я и сам понял. Как мне это записать в переменную и какого типа?

Comment: Точнее так, какого типа переменная должна быть?

Comment: `type string =  Packed Array [1..255] of Char;
var 
pc : string;
c:char;
...
i:=1;
read(f,c);
if c = ' ' then 
pc[i]:=#0 
else
 begin
pc[i]:=c;
i:=i+1;
end;
`

как-то так

Comment: красивше было бы обернуть в repeat ... until

Comment: @Magos, тоже так думал. НО! Мне нужно это сравнить потом с текстом, типа 'Anna'. Сравнение packed прокатит разве? Могу для ясности полностью условие дать.

Comment: @Magos, можно даже лучше в скайпе? Мне для зачета нужно 2 программы завтра сдать, вообще не втупляю некоторые моменты их реализации.

Comment: так и сравните тоже посимвольно. у меня на работе нет компилятора паскаля, не могу привести 100% рабочий код

насколько я помню паскаль может сравнивать и массивы, если они одной длины и одного типа

Comment: кинь условие в скайп (указан в моем профиле). часа через 2 - буду дома, что-нить придумаю